# Finish script on original document.title?

Tags: javascript

The problem I have is that this script finishes on the flash title what would I have to change so that this script finishes with the original document title. Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

```
(function () {

var original = document.title;
var timeout;

window.flashTitle = function (newMsg, howManyTimes) {
    function step() {
        document.title = (document.title == original) ? newMsg : original;

        if (--howManyTimes > 0) {
            timeout = setTimeout(step, 1000);
        };
    };

    howManyTimes = parseInt(howManyTimes);

    if (isNaN(howManyTimes)) {
        howManyTimes = 5;
    };

    cancelFlashTitle(timeout);
    step();
};

window.cancelFlashTitle = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    document.title = original;
};

}());
flashTitle("New Notification");
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the `howManyTimes` var is an even number, if it is an odd number, it will end on the `newMsg`

Comment: o wow @You that makes alot of sense that really does thankyou so much. if you want if you write that as an answer I'd happily mark that as the answer :-) sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Okay, I'll write an answer with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `howManyTimes` var is an even number, if it is an odd number, it will end on the `newMsg`:

```
(function () {

    var original = document.title;
    var timeout;

    window.flashTitle = function (newMsg, howManyTimes) {
        if (isNaN(howManyTimes)) {
            howManyTimes = 5;
        };

        howManyTimes = (howManyTimes % 2 == 0) ? howManyTimes : howManyTimes + 1;

        function step() {
            document.title = (document.title == original) ? newMsg : original;

            if (--howManyTimes > 0) {
                timeout = setTimeout(step, 1000);
            };
        };

        howManyTimes = parseInt(howManyTimes);

        cancelFlashTitle(timeout);
        step();
    };

    window.cancelFlashTitle = function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        document.title = original;
    };

}());
flashTitle("New Notification");
```

**EDIT** - fixed small error